# The new top bar appears on every page when printing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

With sticky headers comes additional problems. This one strongly affects the ability to print pages on our sites, because a sticky top bar apparently gets repeated only every single page of the print document (at least for me in latest Chrome). For example, printing a list of questions results in the first question on every page being covered up:

[image: Overlap on Print Preview]

I don't believe the old top bar was completely *hidden* from the print preview, but why not? The top bar is mostly filled with links and user info, none of which is useful in a printed copy because you can't click a link on paper. As well, since the Stack Overflow logo is a background rather than an image, that gets stripped from the preview too.

So if it's easier, feel free to just completely hide the top bar in the print CSS. But if it needs to stay, at least return it to non-sticky form when printing so it doesn't overlap on every page.

Comment: You can remove stickyness in your SO preferences

Comment: @AntoinePelletier That removes it on the site too, though. I like it on regularly - it doesn't repeat itself every so many pixels down the browser page. Printing is a completely different beast, and it's really never appropriate to leave something sticky while printing, because this happens. And it's certainly not reasonable for a user to have to go disable it every time they want to print something.

Comment: I can't imagine why it would need to display in prints.

Comment: It looks like Stack Overflow has a print style sheet, they should be able to just add a rule to hide the new nav when printing.

Comment: @animuson I agree with you, i was just mentionning this feature

Comment: Given that the response to every other issue with the sticky header is "you can turn it off now, problem solved", I read the comment as tongue in cheek.

Comment: Rather than completely removing the header, it might be good to at least leave the logo there.

Comment: Hope all that sticky stuff didn't clog your printer.

Comment: People are printing out SO content? Blimey!

Comment: I downvoted for the trees.

Comment: Even if your president denies climate change... It is real. Please don't print webpages!!!

Comment: @baao: How else should one cache visited pages?

Comment: Make a screenshot/screen capture, download the site and save it locally  @Cerbrus

Comment: @baao: But what if my computer dies? I still need SO answers to work on my code ;-) (Don't take these comments too seriously)

Comment: @Cerbrus haha, if your computer dies, you can't work on your code anymore.

Comment: @baao: paper ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fix is waiting in repo for next build. So you should be able to print all Stack Overflow pages without header pretty soon.

Comment: What if I want to print the top of the page, with header? (In other words, make it sticky for print?)

Comment: @Cerbrus then you should use user script / custom stylesheet.

Comment: Okay, that comment was more intended as: Instead of simply flat-out removing the nav bar for the print view as workaround, how about a more user-friendly fix that actually _fixes_ the problem?

Comment: @Cerbrus there's no point of having header visible in print because it doesn't give any value - you can't click nav items on paper, use search or open dropdowns. it will be just useless and confusing decoration taking space and making your printer use more paper. and because of that more trees will be cut. also, it _actually fixes the problem_ which was covering content with header on each page. it won't cover it anymore so problem is fixed.

Comment: Actually, this removes the profile rep / badges. Also, the site name / icon isn't shown _anywhere_ on the print. I'd argue that especially the latter one should be visible on a printed page. No point in showing the header? I disagree.

Comment: @Cerbrus profile & rep values change dynamically so after your print specific question you _may_ already have different values. also, i'm not sure how that information would be useful after you print it? as for site name - most browsers add it in header of printing page (it's what <title> tag contains) - Edge doesn't do it by default but you can turn it on really quickly when printing. as for glyph - we don't have offline (print) branding strategy yet, so we can live without it... so that leaves us rep/badges that you gonna miss, right? keeping header to show only this data is not worth it.

Comment: Hm, time for a offline (print) branding strategy ;-) Thanks for the reply, that covers my concerns!

Comment: @Cerbrus i'm working on it - [this](https://cl.ly/142N1B121o1y) is all i've got for now..

Comment: I like it, very retro!

Comment: @Paweł - Stack Ovevflow? Is the branding being changed?!

Comment: @TravisJ yes.. didn't i mention that before? oh, well..